# Right DIV tag not working with padding

Tags: html, css

I have two divs aligned horizontally but the padding for the right div isn't working. I'm trying to add padding to the left of the word: "RIGHT DATA"

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="post-main-content">
  <div class="post-left">
    LEFT DATA  
  </div>
  <div class="post-right">
    RIGHT DATA
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-main-content {
    height:350px;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.post-right {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
}

.post-left {
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

Am I aligning the two divs incorrectly?

You can see a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/7mfsavxm/)

Any thoughts?

Comment: `.post-left` is floated and `.post-right` is not. As a result, `.post-left` is removed from the document flow and `.post-right` actually exists behind it. So, the `padding-left` on `.post-right` exists all the way to the left side of the page, behind `.post-left`. The text inside `.post-right` wraps around the floated `.post-left`, pushing the text to the right and causing the padding on `.post-right` not to affect the text. [Here's a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/7mfsavxm/9/).

Comment: @showdev that helps explain what I'm seeing.  Do I just need to float the post-right div to the right?

Comment: You could [float them both left](http://jsfiddle.net/7mfsavxm/41/). You could also [replace the `padding-left` on `.post-right` with `margin-right` on `.post-left`](http://jsfiddle.net/7mfsavxm/40/), as suggested by Rob Scott. Other answers here also solve the issue in various ways. I just didn't see an explanation of the problem in any of the submitted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `margin-right: 20px;` to the left div b/c the paddings are offsetting each other

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mfsavxm/1/)

Also you need to clear your floats.

See [Clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

---

**EDIT:**

Somebody mentioned border-box, which is also correct. With frameworks such as bootstrap and foundation, these already are associated w/ all element. When you're floating elements next to each other, they need some sort of width applied. If the floated element has either margin, borders, or padding applied, the width calculations done by the browser are done w/o those styles applied. Threrefore, moving your floated element(s) down.

It's always a good idea to add

```
* {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also, the `right-div` had `width: 100%;`. If we change this to use `calc(100% - 100px);` - since the left div has a 100px width, then it works w/o having to add the `margin-right:20px` on the left div

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mfsavxm/39/)

Comment: What do you mean by "paddings are offsetting each other"? It seems more related to only one `<div>` being floated.

Comment: Was my original thought and misread that both divs had "padding-left" assigned", thought one was right and the other was left, but then I saw the float issue.

Comment: @Rob Scott What is the float issue?

Comment: @Rob Scott I had no idea you could calculate css widths on the fly...is this frowned upon?

Comment: @Paul See the [browser compatibility of `calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Comment: Not at all. usually what one would do is apply percentages (ie - leftDiv = 10%, and the rightDiv = 90%). In your case you're using pixels, and to have the right div go the whole way calc is the way to go. This way you don't have to have the rightDIV be something like "850px" or whatever. IMO "calc" is widely NOT used b/c a lot of people "perhaps" have never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the class .post-right have the total width, so give the class margin-left the width+padding of the .post-left

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/jorisros/9y3fdc7o/`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
padding-left: 140px;
```

Since it is horizontal div, padding should count from left most page-content, hence it should be more than 120px.
    http://jsfiddle.net/rvoj81dc/